# How can I escape Special Characters in a value of xsl file for Wix packaging into wxs file

Tags: xslt, wix3.6

I have a code that I am trying to Package and Build on Visual Studio. It looks something like below

XSL to WXS (WiX packaging)

<wix:ServiceInstall Id="abc" Type="xyx" Account="mno" Password="Q.-[Je~m}12%@RT#"

While building, because of the special characters in the Password column, facing error -  ICE03: Invalid format string

I tried to wrap the special characters within blocks []. But of no help.
Also tried placing "" at the beginning of the password value, but still the same error

Any suggestions are appreciated